# On "submit" add new row to table & save to database. Firebase even listener .on("child_added") returning multiple extra undefined rows to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to create a Train Schedule, in which the user adds a new Train via HTML form and submit button. Each train is then added to a table which contains all the trains. Information should be saved using Firebase database so all trains are saved no matter who opens a new window/page. So far I am getting the results I want, but I am getting a few extra 'undefined' results added to the table. I tried to debug, but I can't seem to find why these extra ones are being added.

Here is the HTML Code for the table:

```
    <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="trainName">Train Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="trainName" placeholder="Enter the name of your train">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="destination">Destination</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="destination" placeholder="Enter your train's destination">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstTrainTime">First Train Time (HH:MM Military Time)</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstTrainTime" placeholder="HH:MM">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="frequency">Frequency (min)</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="frequency" placeholder="MM">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="submitBttn">SUBMIT</button>
        </form>

    <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Train Name</th>
                        <th>Destination</th>
                        <th>Frequency (min)</th>
                        <th>Next Arrival</th>
                        <th>Minutes Away</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Trenton Express</td>
                      <td>Trenton</td>
                      <td>25</td>
                      <td>05:35 PM</td>
                      <td>10</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
```

Here is the Javascript code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var userInptTrainName = "";
var userInptDestination = "";
var userInptFirstTT = "";
var userInptFreq = 0;

$("#submitBttn").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    userInptTrainName = $("#trainName").val().trim();
    userInptDestination = $("#destination").val().trim();
    userInptFirstTT = $("#firstTrainTime").val().trim();
    userInptFreq = $("#frequency").val().trim();

    firebase.database().ref().push({
        dataTrainName: userInptTrainName,
        dataDestination: userInptDestination,
        dataFirstTrainTime: userInptFirstTT,
        dataFrequency: userInptFreq,
        timeAdded: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
    });

    firebase.database().ref().limitToLast(1).on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
            var newRowItem = $("<tr><td>" + snapshot.val().dataTrainName + "</td><td>" + snapshot.val().dataDestination + "</td><td>" + snapshot.val().dataFirstTrainTime + "</td><td>" + snapshot.val().dataFrequency + "</td></tr>");
            $("table tbody").append(newRowItem);
    });
});
```

});

I do have the

```
var config = {};
```

in my code, I just deleted it, because it has my firebase info on there.

Comment: Are those undefined results being displayed on the table only? Or do they get inserted in the database? (please check the firebase console to make sure)

Comment: @MWolowicz did you solve this?